# gtk problem on macosx

Tags: python, macos, gtk, homebrew

i installed gtk using homebrew

> brew install gtk
>
> brew info gtk

```
gtk+ 2.20.1

http://www.gtk.org/

Depends on: pkg-config, glib, jpeg, libtiff, pango, jasper, atk 
/usr/local/Cellar/gtk+/2.20.1 (1051 files, 33M)

http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/commits/master/Library/Formula/gtk+.rb
```

after that, i add LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH to /etc/bashrc

but now i using

> import gtk

in python,

> ImportError: No module named gtk

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 4):

[PyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org/) is a separate project. Install that as well.

Comment: brew install pygtk